# SQL Server 2014 .bak file error - The media family on device 'D:\..' is incorrectly formed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Worst case scenario - the server crashed and the 2014 SQL Server `.bak` file had to be recovered from the failed disk. The `.bak` file I have is over 20gb in size but is unusable when trying to restore from it. I built a new server and it is running SQL Server 2014 developer, just like the old server (the new server backs up all the database to the cloud, local drives, virtual drives, and network drives. I also have a script on a cron job to verify all the backup media files daily now as well).

I was able to restore some of the data but now my customer is asking us for a certain date range that I can't provide.

I have been reading a lot about this and everything indicates that it is a SQL Server version related issue however I think it has something to do with how the `.bak` file was recovered (maybe ASCII vs Binary file format?).

I know the data is there or the file wouldn't be over 20gb, I just need to get SQL to recognize it as valid backup media.

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated!

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY 
FROM DISK = 'D:\!Recovered Drives From Old Server\ONTMaster Recovery File\ONTMaster.bak'
GO

RESTORE VERIFYONLY 
FROM DISK = 'D:\!Recovered Drives From Old Server\ONTMaster Recovery File\ONTMaster.bak'
GO
```

Here is the error I receive:

> Msg 3241, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The media family on device 'D:!Recovered Drives From Old Server\ONTMaster Recovery File\ONTMaster.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally.
>   Msg 3241, Level 16, State 0, Line 5
>   The media family on device 'D:!Recovered Drives From Old Server\ONTMaster Recovery File\ONTMaster.bak' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: Are you sure you are restoring to 2014 edition? I ask because I think that's the error you get if you try to restore a backup from a later edition to an earlier edition.

Comment: Thanks!   I posted this question in dba exchange as well.

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure I am restoring from 2014 and the .bak file was created in 2012.  SQL does not even recognize the file as backup media (It says "No backup selected to be restored", even though it is pointing to the correct directory/file).  I am an expert in database recovery but this one has me stumped...

Comment: just a silly question, but is it possible that your path is the issue here? have you tried moving the file to a path that doesn't include an `!`?

Comment: some one asked same questio here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/37cc6600-3662-4d3e-8ea8-516837828776/the-media-family-on-device-is-incorrectly-formed

Answer (score 2):

There can be several causes for this error:

1. The backup is corrupted as it has not been transferred in binary mode If you are using FTP to transfer the backup, make sure the file is transferred in binary mode
2. The version of your backup is different than the SQL Server instance you are trying to restore it to. You can try to restore to a SQL server instance with the right version and transfer the data with SSIS
3. The backup is corrupt. In this case your options are limited

Comment: I found this .bak recovery SW on technet.       https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Easily-Recover-SQL-Backup-9c79e2ac   hopefully I will be able to simulate the tables so I can recover the data using SSIS.  Thanks everyone and I will confirm this did the trick.

Comment: So I tried moving the bak file to a different location (without the explanation mark) and did not have any luck.  It does not recognize the file as backup media.  I need to somehow convert the file to binary, I believe it is in ASCII format when it was recovered from the failed hard drive.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to convert it from ASCII back to binary. Do you or your IT department still have access to the failed drive ?

Comment: Yes, I still have the failed drive.

Comment: Can you copy the backup again, in this case using binary transfer mode?

Comment: How do I transfer the files in binary mode?

Comment: Xcopy should do the trick.

Comment: These drives were actually sent to a data recovery facility that cost a fortune because they are 2TB drives.  Do you know of any HDD software recovery applications I can use to extract the files using xcopy?  Thanks

Comment: It looks like I will know the results from the XCopy tomorrow morning.  Hopefully the backup media will be valid!